# How can I use .jsonp jquery to retrive data from a url?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how can I use `.jsonp` jquery to retrieve data from a URL? I have written the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
$.JSONP({
    url: 'http://test.com',
    callbackKey: 'jsoncallback',
    onComplete: function (data) {
        alert(data)
        // the request was completed.
    }
});
```

NOTE: the url working fine

Comment: `$.JSONP`? Have you invented that utility function?

Comment: @Raminson https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `$.JSONP` ? The simplest way to do this is as follows

```
var url="http://scoreboardwcf.sportal.com.au/scoreboard.svc/GetCalendarData?BaseURL=http://www.sportal.com.au/&Sport=All&CompetitionID=0&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  alert(data);  
});
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/fk8jD/3/).

**Update:** Since you asked in the comment - How can I apply it into for loop instead ?

```
var url="http://scoreboardwcf.sportal.com.au/scoreboard.svc/GetCalendarData?BaseURL=http://www.sportal.com.au/&Sport=All&CompetitionID=0&callback=?";

$.getJSON(url,  function(data) {
    document.write('DefaultFixtureNo : '+data.Calendar.DefaultFixtureNo+'<br /><br />');
    var items=data.Calendar.FixtureData;
    for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        var item=items[i];
        for(x in item) document.write(x+' : '+item[x]+'<br />');
        document.write('<br /><br />');
    }
});
```

[Example Here using for loop](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/fk8jD/4/).

Comment: how can I apply it into for loop instead?

Comment: It's interesting, but in Opera 12.10 if URL din't contain .json extension I get HTML (not XHR) request. Using jQuery 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

This would help you,

```
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: "http://scoreboardwcf.sportal.com.au/scoreboard.svc/GetCalendarData?BaseURL=http://www.sportal.com.au/&Sport=All&CompetitionID=0&callback=?";,
            success: function () {alert('Success');},
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

How to perform a http GET request using $.jsonp

Example comes from stackoverflow question on performing http-method besides GET

["jquery.jsonp.js" GET works. What about POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684090/jquery-jsonp-js-get-works-what-about-post-put-delete-options)

```
$.jsonp({
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://www.mydomain.com/logicalurl/2/',
    callbackParameter: 'callback',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(json, textStatus, xOptions) {
        myglob = json;
        MyModulePatternObject.initNew(json);
    },
    error: function (xOptions, textStatus) {
        console.log("fail");
    }
});
```

`myglob` is for seeing and manipulating the json response while debugging in Tools->Web Developer->Web Console . Also use Firebug

`MyModulePatternObject.initNew(json)` is just the renamed method which is called after a successful jsonp request.

`cache: false,` Recommend using `PageCache: true,` on production code. While developing the app keep the cache off.